# Why my encrypt method doesn't work, encoding without string argument?

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I made a bin file without extension, and that file contain a text that is encrypted, the problem is that when I want to retrieve the text I get this error message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\conitc11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\conitc11\Desktop\PY\REPORTEBIOSTAR.py", line 338, in
LecturaBinario
    encrypted_text = pad(bytes(content, 'utf-8'), 16)
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Here is the code

```
def EncrypConfig(message):  
    entryMessage = pad(bytes(message, 'utf-8'), 16)
    obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    print('Original message is: ', entryMessage)
    #PAD = lambda s: s + (32 - len(s) % 32)*''
    encrypted_text = obj.encrypt(entryMessage)
    print('The encrypted text', encrypted_text)
    return encrypted_text
def CreacionBinario():
    f = open('cfg', 'wb')
    #byte_arr = [120, 3, 255, 0, 100]
    #byte_arr = [columnasConfig[0], columnasConfig[1], columnasConfig[2]]
    columnasConfig[0] = cbDepartamento.get()   
    columnasConfig[1] = '2345G564D5645'
    columnasConfig[2] = lector.get()
    #counterBoy = 0
    #for x in range(3):
    #binary_format = columnasConfig[x]
    EncrypConfig(columnasConfig[0])
    print('Texto a encryptar: ' + columnasConfig[0])
    f.write((bytes(str(EncrypConfig(columnasConfig[0])), 'utf-8')))
    print('Texto encryptado: ' + str(EncrypConfig(columnasConfig[0])))
    #counterBoy += 1
    #print(str(counterBoy - 1) + ' CONTADO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    f.close()
def LecturaBinario():
    '''
    f = open('cfg', 'w+b')
    rev_obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    decrypted_text = rev_obj.decrypt(encrypted_text)
    #for x in range(2):
    columnasConfig[0] = f.readline(decrypted_text)
    f.close()
    print('columna 0 ' + columnasConfig[0] + ' columna 1 ' + columnasConfig[1]+ ' columna 2 ' + columnasConfig[2])
    '''
    #CreacionBinario()
    with open('cfg', 'rb') as fh:
        content = fh.read()
    print('Content:' + str(content))
    #encrypted_text = pad(bytes(str(content), 'utf-8'), 16)
    encrypted_text = pad(bytes(content, 'utf-8'), 16)
    rev_obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)    
    decrypted_text = rev_obj.decrypt(encrypted_text)
    print("Print the full content of the binary file:")
    print(content)
    print("DecriptedText: ", decrypted_text.decode('utf-8'))
```

This is the sample code i'm using, i tried not using bytes in content just pad and it display the next error "DecriptedText:  <built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x0000019C7EFDFC00>" instead of the decoded output, without pad and bytes the result is "ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode"

```
from email.message import Message
from os import urandom
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad

# For Generating cipher text
secret_key = urandom(16)
iv = urandom(16)
obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

message = pad(bytes('All Users', 'utf-8'), 16)
print('Original message is: ', message)
encrypted_text = obj.encrypt(message)
print('The encrypted text', encrypted_text)

# Decrypt the message
rev_obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decrypted_text = rev_obj.decrypt(encrypted_text)
print('The decrypted text', decrypted_text.decode('utf-8'))
```

SOLUTION.

Well at first place i saw the comments but i didn't understand what they was saying, they gave me the idea of replacing or changing several code lines the next code line

```
message = pad(bytes(str(text), 'utf-8'), 16)
```

replaced this one

```
entryMessage = pad(bytes(message, 'utf-8'), 16)
```

This change has no effect in the code but i replace it to have a better order also i moved the line down of the next line

```
obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

The next change was replacing this line

```
f.write(EncrypConfig(listOfConfig))
```

instead of this line

```
 f.write((bytes(str(EncrypConfig(columnasConfig[0])), 'utf-8')))
```

This change was the most important, next to this i delete the next line of code

```
encrypted_text = pad(bytes(content, 'utf-8'), 16)
```

and some other changes the final result and THE SOLUTION is this:

```
secret_key = b'somebinarykey12'
iv = b'somebinaryvalue1'
def EncrypConfig(text):
    obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)  
    message = pad(bytes(str(text), 'utf-8'), 16) 
    encrypted_text = obj.encrypt(message)
    return encrypted_text
def CreacionBinario():
    f = open('cfg', 'wb')
    columnasConfig[0] = cbDepartamento.get()   
    columnasConfig[1] = txtContraseñaSave.get()
    columnasConfig[2] = lector.get()
    columnasConfig[3] = checkedLilWindow2.get()    
    listOfConfig = [columnasConfig[0], columnasConfig[1], columnasConfig[2], columnasConfig[3]]
    f.write(EncrypConfig(listOfConfig))
    print('Texto a encryptar: ', listOfConfig)   
    print('Texto encryptado: ', EncrypConfig(listOfConfig))
    f.close()
def LecturaBinario():
    with open('cfg', 'rb') as fh:
        content = fh.read()
    print('Content:', content)
    rev_obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)    
    decrypted_text = rev_obj.decrypt(content)
    print("Print the full content of the binary file:")
    print(content)
    print('The decrypted text: ', decrypted_text.decode('utf-8'))
    listFromFile = list[decrypted_text.decode('utf-8')]
    return listFromFile[1]
```

Comment: `content` was read from a binary file, so is already a `bytes` object.  Probably just need `pad(content,16)` but this isn't a [mcve] to test.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `bytes(content, 'utf-8')`, what do you think this means? What do you expect `content` to be? Did you test that? What kind of thing is it? (Hint: how did you get `content`? By `.read`ing it from the file, right? See where it says `with open('cfg', 'rb') as fh:`? What do you think the `'rb'` part means? Therefore, what will end up in `content`? Is there a need to use a string encoding with that? Why?)

Comment: i tried many thinks not converting it was one of them if i doesn't use the pad, i get an error if i don't use the bytes convert i get another error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION.

Well at first place i saw the comments but i didn't understand what they was saying, they gave me the idea of replacing or changing several code lines the next code line

```
message = pad(bytes(str(text), 'utf-8'), 16)
```

replaced this one

```
entryMessage = pad(bytes(message, 'utf-8'), 16)
```

This change has no effect in the code but i replace it to have a better order also i moved the line down of the next line

```
obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

The next change was replacing this line

```
f.write(EncrypConfig(listOfConfig))
```

instead of this line

```
f.write((bytes(str(EncrypConfig(columnasConfig[0])), 'utf-8')))
```

This change was the most important, next to this i delete the next line of code

```
encrypted_text = pad(bytes(content, 'utf-8'), 16)
```

and some other changes the final result and THE SOLUTION is this:

```
secret_key = b'somebinarykey12'
iv = b'somebinaryvalue1'
def EncrypConfig(text):
    obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)  
    message = pad(bytes(str(text), 'utf-8'), 16) 
    encrypted_text = obj.encrypt(message)
    return encrypted_text
def CreacionBinario():
    f = open('cfg', 'wb')
    columnasConfig[0] = cbDepartamento.get()   
    columnasConfig[1] = txtContraseñaSave.get()
    columnasConfig[2] = lector.get()
    columnasConfig[3] = checkedLilWindow2.get()    
    listOfConfig = [columnasConfig[0], columnasConfig[1], columnasConfig[2], columnasConfig[3]]
    f.write(EncrypConfig(listOfConfig))
    print('Texto a encryptar: ', listOfConfig)   
    print('Texto encryptado: ', EncrypConfig(listOfConfig))
    f.close()
def LecturaBinario():
    with open('cfg', 'rb') as fh:
        content = fh.read()
    print('Content:', content)
    rev_obj = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)    
    decrypted_text = rev_obj.decrypt(content)
    print("Print the full content of the binary file:")
    print(content)
    print('The decrypted text: ', decrypted_text.decode('utf-8'))
    listFromFile = list[decrypted_text.decode('utf-8')]
    return listFromFile[1]
```